# MVC - Layout keeps displaying menus after logging out

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm currently working on a website that follows a guide on plural-sight.
I'm having two main issues with the web application:

1. After logging out, items that are under the following `if` statement are still showing up:

   ```
                       @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                   {
                       <li class="nav-item btn-group">
                           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down"> @User.Identity.Name </span> </a>
                           <div class="dropdown-menu">
                               <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Account"> Account <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="Settings"> Settings <i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                               <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Logout" asp-action="Logout"> Logout <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                           </div>
                       </li>
                   }
   ```
2. The second problem is hiding menus from users who are logged in:

   ```
                       @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                   {
                       <li class="nav-item @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Contact" ? "active" : "")">
                           <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">
                           <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="About" asp-action="About">About</a>
                       </li>
                   }
   ```

If `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns a Boolean I'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

[Picture of my NavBar displaying menus after login out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO1BH.jpg)

I'll provide more details if needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try to set a breakpoint on your `if` statements and check to make sure the value of `IsAuthenticated` is correct? Have you tried anything else to figure out what is causing this?

Comment: Also, I copy-pasted what you have here, and I'm using Windows authentication and I'm just seeing the content of the first `if`, like I would expect, since I'm logged in. `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true` for me. (I'm also using fontawesome so I see the icon, but that doesn't really matter)

Comment: So when clicking logout the razor layout view is rendered before the async public async Task<IActionResult> Logout() is done?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I didn't try logging out at all, I just pasted your code and hit run and since I'm automatically logged in through Windows authentication, I only see the first part that is within the `if` that checks `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: For my first problem, if I refresh the page the username drop-down disappears as intended. But I want it to be gone as soon as they get redirected to the logout page.

Comment: The second problem is working now. I'm not sure what happened that made it work as intended now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `SignOut()`, the user is logged off on the next (http)request.

So

1. Do a redirect
2. Or  Force log out. The seems only be possible in non-core ASP.Net: To log off immediately, clear the `User` property with a default value:

   ```
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    //log off immediately
    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
   ```

Comment: I'm using SignInManager from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity. I'm not sure how I would force a log off immediately.

Comment: Ah .Net Core wasn't clear. Afaik this isn't possible in .Net core

Comment: I'll just have to create a seperate layout for the logout page. :/